# Error: FIRESTORE (10.7.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Got the above error in Flutter when using collection group query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error due to missing permissions for collection group queries even though I had the below permission for the subcollection `posts` in `forums` collection

```
    match /forums/{forumid}/posts/{post} {
      // Only authenticated users can read
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      // Only the post author can write
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
    }
```

I found [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules) which states:

> In your security rules, you must explicitly allow collection group queries by writing a rule for the collection group:
>
> 1. Make sure `rules_version = '2';` is the first line of your ruleset. Collection group queries require the new recursive wildcard `{name=**}` behavior of security rules version 2.
> 2. Write a rule for you collection group using `match /{path=**}/[COLLECTION_ID]/{doc}`.

So updating permissions like below works

```
    match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /forums/{forumid}/posts/{postid} {
      // Only a post's author can write to a post
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;

    }
```

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63138331/13521429)